# not able to use libx265 'no-info=1' in 2 pass

Tags: ffmpeg

What's wrong with the below command? I am not able to use `no-info=1` in 2 pass encoding hevc

```
ffmpeg -y -i "test.mkv" -map 0 -c copy -t 10 -c:v libx265 -b:v 1000k -x265-params "pass=1:no-info=1" -vf "scale=1280:-2" -an -f null /dev/null && ffmpeg -i "test.mkv" -map 0 -c copy -t 10 -c:v libx265 -b:v 1000k -x265-params "pass=2:no-info=2" -vf "scale=1280:-2" -c:a copy "output.mkv"
```

Does it works only with crf or what please help?

Answer (score 0):

Should be `no-info=1`, not `no-info=2`:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "test.mkv" -map 0 -c copy -t 10 -c:v libx265 -b:v 1000k -x265-params "pass=1:no-info=1" -vf "scale=1280:-2" -an -f null /dev/null && ffmpeg -i "test.mkv" -map 0 -c copy -t 10 -c:v libx265 -b:v 1000k -x265-params "pass=2:no-info=1" -vf "scale=1280:-2" -c:a copy "output.mkv"
```